# Why is a C structure returning misaligned junk data when read from Rust?

Tags: rust, ffi

I am trying to wrap a C function in Rust. The C function `struct elem* get_list()` returns the following struct:

```c
struct elem {
    char data[5],
    struct elem* next
};
```

In Rust, I have declared the function the following way. The declaration of the C function returns `*const c_void` as described in an old version of the Rust documentation, which I could not find at the time of writing. I tried returning `*const elem` and working with pointers, achieving the same result:

```
extern "C" {
    pub fn get_list() -> *const c_void;
}
```

The struct represents a linked list, with `next` being a pointer to the next element of the list. Inside Rust, I declared the struct in the following way:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct elem {
    pub data: [u8; 5],
    pub next: *const c_void,
}
```

The function returns a `*const c_void` pointer to the first element of the linked list (of type `elem`). I'm trying to read the elements of the linked list with the following code:

```
let head = get_list();
while !head.is_null() {
    let el: &elem = mem::transmute(head);
    let str = el.data;
    let str = CStr::from_bytes_with_nul(&str).unwrap();
    //do something
    head = el.next();
}
```

This reads junk data - the pointers are not properly aligned, both the string is bad and non-null-terminated, and the next pointer leads to random data (the list had different size when the function is called from C directly).

I tried with the function returning a pointer to `elem` and only working with pointers, I tried with transmuting `str` from the address of `el` - it always reads the same junk data. How do I make it align properly?

I know how to do it with a pointer instead of an array and that's the way it is demonstrated in the Rust documentation, but I cannot change the C code.

Comment: How is the C implementation of `get_list` declared? (I am curious about why you have it returning `*const c_void` instead of `*const elem`.)

Comment: [It should be working](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5f56804e93f608e811727af85d376f52&version=stable)

Comment: also, at what point in the iteration are you seeing misaligned data being read out? Is the initial `head = get_list()` misaligned? Or is it only sometime after the first iteration?

Comment: Your problem is not in the code you've shown. We need to see a [MCVE].

Comment: Why (and how) are you calling a *function* next, when it's declared as a pointer?

Comment: Adding to the previous MCVE comment, if you could provide a (small!) version of the C code you are linking against, that would allow us to compile and link against it ourselves. Something that defines `get_list` would be a good start. Is that struct a global, is it being allocated, etc. That way, we can use tools like a debugger as well as rapidly iterate to a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I wrote an example library just for this case, I found out it wasn't an extern problem, rather a `CStr` one. As it is fixed in the example, where I slice the buffer to the position of the first NUL terminator, I provide the example I wrote for proper externing.

**list.c**

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct elem {
    char data[5];
    struct elem* next;
};

struct elem* get_list() {
    struct elem* head = malloc(sizeof(struct elem));
    strcpy(head->data, "1");

    struct elem* el = malloc(sizeof(struct elem));
    head->next = el;

    strcpy(el->data, "2");

    el->next = malloc(sizeof(struct elem));
    el = el->next;
    strcpy(el->data, "3");
    el->next = NULL;

    return head;
}
```

**main.rs**

```
use std::ffi::CStr;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct elem {
    pub data: [u8; 5],
    pub next: *const elem
}

#[link(name = "list", kind = "static")]
extern {
    pub fn get_list() -> *const elem;
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let mut list = get_list();
        // Note, that, if we call from_bytes_with_nul it will throw  
        // an NulInternal error, therefore,
        // we have to slice the buffer to the first NUL-terminator
        while !list.is_null() {
            let mut null_pos = (*list).data.len() - 1;
            {
                for i in 0..(*list).data.len() {
                    if (*list).data[i] == 0 {
                        null_pos = i + 1;
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
            let str = CStr::from_bytes_with_nul(
                          (*list).data[..null_pos]
                      ).unwrap();
            println!("{:?}", str);
            list = (*list).next;
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
"1"
"2"
"3"
```

Key aspects of the implementation:

- Define the same structure, annotated with `#[repr(C)]`, so it would be
  aligned in the same way as the C one.
- Define the extern function to return a const pointer to the structure.
- Use pointers instead of `std::mem::transmute`
- Be careful with null pointers and terminators

Comment: And *that's* why we want people to provide a [MCVE].